# Is there a more elegant way to declare my javascript variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a hangman game and it's working great, but this block of variables is really quite ugly. I know I've done something in PHP before where I've put all the variables I've needed into an array and pumped them out. Is there a way to accomplish this with Javascript while grabbing my DOM elements?

```
let _ = [];
let correct = [];
let wrong = [];
let underscores = document.querySelector('.underscores');
let correctBlock = document.querySelector('.correct');
let wrongBlock = document.querySelector('.wrong');
let scoreBlock = document.querySelector('#score');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let hint = document.querySelector('.hint');
```

Comment: You can declare your variables with `let a = 1, b = 2, ...` to avoid repeating `let`.

Comment: Are you talking about `register_globals($array)` in PHP? There's nothing like that in JS, and it's not commonly used in PHP either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're referring to the double `$` in PHP? (it's been a while)

No, sorry.

I suggest you create a map to keep things contained:

```
let score = {
  _: [],
  correct: [],
  wrong: []
}

let blocks = {
  underscores: document.querySelector('.underscores'),
  correct: document.querySelector('.correct'),
  wrong: document.querySelector('.wrong'),
  score: document.querySelector('#score')
}

let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let hint = document.querySelector('.hint');
```

Usage:

```
score.wrong.push('...')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much. Not sure why I was downvoted haha, this seems way more elegant

Comment: Yea I dunno either.  Happy to help :)

Comment: This is nice, didn't think outside the blocks, uhm, I meant, box. OP wanted a more elegant, not a terse solution, so here we have it

Answer (score 1):

The shortest you'll be able to get is:

```
let _ = [],
  correct = [],
  wrong = [],
  underscores = document.querySelector('.underscores'),
  correctBlock = document.querySelector('.correct'),
  wrongBlock = document.querySelector('.wrong'),
  scoreBlock = document.querySelector('#score'),
  btn = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  hint = document.querySelector('.hint');
```

I can't see a way to generalize/compress this, as the elements you are selecting are all different. Honestly, this is fine!

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I was thinking that if I put everything into an array things would look nice, but I'm thinking its not possible. Thanks for the updated block!

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I like to group my controls in a structure, but I can't say its better.

```
let ctrls = {
    underscores: document.querySelector('.underscores'),
    correctBlock: document.querySelector('.correct')
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map with parallel assignment. Shorter, but I personally wouldn't do it this way:

```
let [underscores, correctBlock, wrongBlock, scoreBlock, btn, hint] = 
  ['.underscores', '.correct', '.wrong', '#score', '.btn', '.hint']
  .map(selector => document.querySelector(selector))
```

Comment: Interesting!  I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare static variables e.g. functions, references to elements with *const* keyword (instead of *let*).
Instead of repeating let/const keyword, just use [comma operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
const underscores = document.querySelector('.underscores'),
      correctBlock = document.querySelector('.correct'),
      wrongBlock = document.querySelector('.wrong');
```

etc.